# Help me get this for comprehension right

Tags: scala

I have the following (working) code

```
val superSuperSorts = superSorts.flatMap(relations.get(_)).flatMap(x=>x)
```

And I give you the types here

```
val superSorts: Set[Sort]
val relations: Map[Sort, Set[Sort]]
```

Changing it to this for-comprehension gives me a compile error

```
val superSuperSorts = 
  for(
  ss <- superSorts;
  sss <- relations.get(ss); //get Option[Set[Sort]] and flatten the option
  s <- sss                  //extract the elements from the Set
) yield s
```

of this reading

```
error: type mismatch; 
found   : scala.collection.immutable.Set[edu.uulm.scbayes.logic.Sort] 
required: Option[?] 
s <- sss
```

Please explain why my for-comprehension is wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't `flatMap` an Option. Have a look at its type signature:

```
def flatMap [B] (f: (A) ⇒ Option[B]): Option[B]
```

So, `flatMap` unpacks the Option, but requires a new Option, so you need an alternative. You can use the method `getOrElse` of Map or method `seq` of Option:

```
val superSuperSorts = for {
  s <- superSorts
  ss <- relations.getOrElse(s, Set.empty)
} yield s

val superSuperSorts = for {
  s <- superSorts
  ss <- relations.get(s).seq
  sss <- ss
} yield sss
```

Another problem is, that your `flatMap` code is not equivalent with your for-expression. The expression

```
for (x <- expr1; y <- expr2) yield expr3
```

is translated to

```
expr1.flatMap(x => for (y <- expr2) yield expr3)
```

and in another step to

```
expr1.flatMap(x => expr2.map(y => expr3))
```

But you have:

```
expr1.flatMap(x => expr2).flatMap(y => expr3)
```

Comment: I thought I can use the for-comprehension to flatten the Option.

Comment: It does check  this code:   val m=Map(1 -> "a", 2 -> "b").   for(lx <- List(1,3); a <- m.get(lx)) yield a.  Observe the return type!

Comment: @Andreas: `get` returns the type of the value. In the example of the question there is `Set[Int]` returned, not `Int`. Therefore `superSuperSorts` will have type `Set[Set[Int]]` and not `Set[Int]`.

Comment: That the flatMap version and the for version are not equivalent was obvious (because one works). But thank you for explaining how one gets converted to the other. I completely missed that point.

Comment: I corrected it. Thanks for the hint. Hope there isn't another mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Let me give an example to make clear where the problem is. Let's say you have:

```
val superSorts = Set('x)
val relations = Map('x -> Set('a, 'b))
```

This code:

```
val superSuperSorts = 
  for(
  ss <- superSorts;
  sss <- relations.get(ss); //get Option[Set[Sort]] and flatten the option
  s <- sss                  //extract the elements from the Set
) yield s
```

translates to:

```
superSorts.flatMap(
  ss => relations.get(ss).flatMap(
    sss => sss.map(
      s => s)))
```

First, note that the last term is a `map`, not a `flatMap`. Now, let's consider an iteration with the data above:

```
ss = 'x
sss = Set('a, 'b)
s = 'a, 'b
```

And now let's go backward in the code.

```
// Set('a, 'b) => Set('a, 'b)
sss.map(s => s) 

// Some(Set('a, 'b)) => Some('a, 'b)????
relations.get(ss).flatMap(...)
```

See the problem here? How can an `Option[Set[Sort]]` be flattened? There's no such a thing as a `Some('a, 'b)`.

So, why does the original code work?

```
val superSuperSorts = superSorts.flatMap(relations.get(_)).flatMap(x=>x)
```

If we break it down:

```
// Set('x) => Set(Set('a, 'b))
superSorts.flatMap(relations.get(_))

// Set(Set('a, 'b')) => Set('a, 'b)
(...).flatMap(x=>x)
```

See how all the `flatMap` are being applied over a `Set`, not an `Option`? The `Option` was eliminated by the `flatMap` and never came into play.

The more-or-less equivalent for-comprehension for your code would be:

```
val superSuperSorts = for {
  x <- (for {
    ss <- superSorts
    sss <- relations.get(ss)
  } yield sss)
  s <- x
} yield s
```

This introduces a couple of identity maps: `map(sss => sss)` and `map(s => s)`, which get around the fact that the last generator in a for-comprehension is always a `map`.

Comment: The problem I had was that I didn't realize there is a difference between chaining and nesting the flatMaps. Or: I didn't notice that the flatMaps inside the for-comprehension get nested. I think I should use more for-comprehensions to get a feeling for that. Thank you for your explanations.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand that a for comprehension will yield the type of collection fed in. So why your code didn't work is you want to return a single element(s). Try this:

```
val superSuperSorts = 
  for(
  ss <- superSorts;
  sss <- relations.get(ss); //get Option[Set[Sort]] and flatten the option
) yield sss
```

:/ Hope this helps

Comment: So this returns a `Set[Set[Sort]]`? But I want it to be flattened.

Comment: Right my answer is misleading to your question. The key point was explained spot on by Antoras. Since your Map operation returns a single Option you have to repack / construct your resultset from that.